# Lagged cumulative sum for time series based off of multiple conditions

Tags: r, time-series, lubridate, cumulative-sum, cumsum

I'd like to get the cumulative sum of the corresponding records in the `smaller` column for each name under `Species_a` and `Species_b` as two new columns, and have them in the same row without including the value for that row. the `smaller` column lists which species column has a smaller width.

```
  Species_a Species_b Sepal.Width_a Sepal.Width_b  Date        smaller
1 versicolor virginica           2.5           3.0 2022-05-05       a
2 versicolor virginica           2.6           2.8 2022-04-04       a
3 versicolor    setosa           2.2           4.4 2021-03-03       a
4     setosa virginica           4.2           2.5 2021-02-02       b
5  virginica    setosa           3.0           3.4 2020-01-01       a
```

Ideally the format of the data would be in the same format as it is now, and the summation would be based off of the `smaller`, `Date`, `Species_a`, and `Species_b` columns alone. I tried to create a count column but I get stuck on properly accumulating based on `Date` being less than the current value for that column.

My desired output would be as follows:

```
   Species_a Species_b Sepal.Width_a Sepal.Width_b       Date smaller smaller_sum_a smaller_sum_b
1 versicolor virginica           2.5           3.0 2022-05-05       a             2             2
2 versicolor virginica           2.6           2.8 2022-04-04       a             1             2
3 versicolor    setosa           2.2           4.4 2021-03-03       a             0             0
4     setosa virginica           4.2           2.5 2021-02-02       b             0             1
5  virginica    setosa           3.0           3.4 2020-01-01       a             0             0
```

**Code**:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12)

data_a <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)), ] %>% 
  head()
colnames(data_a) <- paste0(colnames(data_a), "_a")

data_b <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)), ] %>% 
  tail()
colnames(data_b) <- paste0(colnames(data_b), "_b")

data <- bind_cols(data_a, data_b) %>% 
  filter(Species_a != Species_b) %>% 
  select(Species_a,
         Species_b, 
         Sepal.Width_a,
         Sepal.Width_b) %>% 
  mutate(Date = c('2022-05-05', '2022-04-04', '2021-03-03', '2021-02-02', '2020-01-01'),
         smaller = ifelse(Sepal.Width_a > Sepal.Width_b, 'b', 
                          ifelse(Sepal.Width_a < Sepal.Width_b, 'a', NA)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a solution, but it might be a start.

How exactly are the new columns calculated? Looks like `smaller_sum_a` is the number of consecutive rows where species `a` has the smaller value, minus one. But the same doesn't work for `smaller_sum_b` I don't think? Or is it just cumulative number of days where each species is has the smaller value, minus 1, but with zero if the species isn't smaller in that row (again this doesn't check out for `smaller_sum_b` though...).

As for determining if `Date` is less than the current value, firstly you'll want to tell R that your `Date` column is actually a date, rather than just a character.

Easiest way to see what format it is in is to make your `data` (not a good name for your data btw, preferably make it something that R or the computer wouldn't use, like `my_data`) a `tibble` rather than a `data.frame`. `tibble`s tell you what format each column is in which is handy.

```
data %>% 
  tibble 

# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   Species_a  Species_b Sepal.Width_a Sepal.Width_b Date       smaller
#   <fct>      <fct>             <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>      <chr>  
# 1 versicolor virginica           2.5           3   2022-05-05 a      
# 2 versicolor virginica           2.6           2.8 2022-04-04 a      
# 3 versicolor setosa              2.2           4.4 2021-03-03 a      
# 4 setosa     virginica           4.2           2.5 2021-02-02 b      
# 5 virginica  setosa              3             3.4 2020-01-01 a
```

The bits inside the `<  >` under the column names tell you the formats, `<fct>` is `factor`, `<dbl>` is `numeric` ([see here for explanation](https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-does-dbl-in-r-stand-for/30599)) and `<chr>` is `character`.

So, we want to make `Date` into a `date` format, which we can do with the `ymd()` (year-month-day) function from `lubridate`. Also, I rearranged the data so the rows are in chronological order (earliest at the top), because that's how things are normally arranged, and makes more sense to me, especially if you're interested in cumulative sums.

```
data %>% 
  tibble %>% 
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(Date)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  {. ->> my_data}

my_data

# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   Species_a  Species_b Sepal.Width_a Sepal.Width_b Date       smaller
#   <fct>      <fct>             <dbl>         <dbl> <date>     <chr>  
# 1 virginica  setosa              3             3.4 2020-01-01 a      
# 2 setosa     virginica           4.2           2.5 2021-02-02 b      
# 3 versicolor setosa              2.2           4.4 2021-03-03 a      
# 4 versicolor virginica           2.6           2.8 2022-04-04 a      
# 5 versicolor virginica           2.5           3   2022-05-05 a
```

We can see that R now recognises that the `Date` column is a date, and is now in the R-recognised `<date>` format.

Now this is where I'm not 100% sure on exactly how you want to calculate your new columns, but for example you can use `ifelse()` to determine if species a is smaller, and then calculate the cumulative sum of the days where it was smaller.

```
my_data %>%
  mutate(
    s_a = ifelse(smaller == 'a', 1, 0),
    smaller_sum_a = cumsum(s_a),
  )
  
# # A tibble: 5 x 8
#   Species_a  Species_b Sepal.Width_a Sepal.Width_b Date       smaller   s_a smaller_sum_a
#   <fct>      <fct>             <dbl>         <dbl> <date>     <chr>   <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 virginica  setosa              3             3.4 2020-01-01 a           1             1
# 2 setosa     virginica           4.2           2.5 2021-02-02 b           0             1
# 3 versicolor setosa              2.2           4.4 2021-03-03 a           1             2
# 4 versicolor virginica           2.6           2.8 2022-04-04 a           1             3
# 5 versicolor virginica           2.5           3   2022-05-05 a           1             4
```

As long as either a) the `Date` column is in an R-recognised `<date>` format, or b) it is arranged chronologically, you can use the *less than* or *greater than* operators `<` & `>` to determine if dates are before/after a given row.

This is a good resource for understanding how R treats dates and times, and is well worth a read https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, and apologize for poor naming convention on the reproducible example. Unfortunately the cumulative sum needs to be lagged as well as unique to a given name, and that name can show up within both `Species_a` and `Species_b`. I figured out a way to do it and I'll post the answer here if you are curious. My result is not ideal since it makes adding new data a little bit more complicated, but if you have any more tips I'd appreciate it!

Comment: All good, as long as you found a solution. The `lag()` (and `lead()`) function(s) from `dplyr` might be useful for you, as you can choose to extract previous values and specific number of observations to go back etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution, I'd like to not use plyr if I can help it since I heard it breaks some of dplyr's functions. I feel like there is definitely a more efficient and modern way of solving this issue but I can't seem to find it.

```
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)

# creating counts for smaller sums for red side

data$Date <- lubridate::parse_date_time(x = data$Date, # standardizing date (outside of the reproducible example there are two date types)
                                              orders = c("%m/%d/%Y", "%Y-%m-%d"))

A_rn <- mutate(filter(select(data, 
                             Species_a, 
                             Date, 
                             smaller), 
                      smaller == 'a'), 
                      smaller_ct_a  = 1)

# creating counts for smaller sums for b
BtoA_rn <- mutate(filter(select(data, 
                                Species_b, 
                                Date, 
                                smaller), 
                         smaller == 'b'), # calling Species_b Species_a for easier joining
                  Species_a = Species_b,
                  smaller_ct_a  = 1) %>% 
  select(Species_a, Date, smaller, smaller_ct_a)

# cumsum for both a and b
A <- ddply(bind_rows(A_rn, BtoA_rn) %>% 
             arrange(Date),
           .(Species_a), transform,
           smaller_sum_a = lag(cumsum(replace_na(smaller_ct_a, 0)))) %>% 
  select(-smaller_ct_a)

# naming adjustment
B <- A %>% filter(smaller == "b") %>% 
  select(-smaller)

names(B) <- gsub(x = names(B), pattern = "_a", replacement = "_b")  
A <- A %>% filter(smaller == "a") %>% 
  select(-smaller)

data <- left_join(data, A, by = c("Species_a", "Date")) %>% 
  left_join(B, by = c("Species_b", "Date"))

data[is.na(data)] <- 0
```